# Filter a 2D Array From Elements of Another

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, array-difference

I have two sets of numeric elements stored as 2D array. The values were grabbed from a column using `.getValues()`. One is a full list the other is a partial list. I want a function that returns full list minus partial list.

- The `partialListArr` may contain duplicates. The `fullListArr` does
  not.
- I need the output to also be a 2D list as they will be used in `.setValues()`.
- Values are all numbers.

Here is what I've tried.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var partialListArr = ss.getSheetByName('sheet 2').getRange(1,1,357,1).getValues();
  var fullListArr = ss.getSheetByName('sheet 1').getRange(1,1,942,1).getValues();

  var arr = fullListArr.filter(function(item){
    return partialListArr.indexOf(item.id) === -1;
  }); 

  Logger.log(arr.length)
  Logger.log(arr)
}
```

This returns the full list.

I also tried this:

```
function myFunction2(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var partialListArr = ss.getSheetByName('sheet 2').getRange(1,1,357,1).getValues();
  var fullListArr = ss.getSheetByName('sheet 1').getRange(1,1,942,1).getValues();

  var arr = fullListArr.map(function(e){return e[0];})
    .filter(function(e,i,a){return (a.indexOf(e)==i && partialListArr.indexOf(e) ==-1); })  

  Logger.log(arr.length)
  Logger.log(arr)
}
```

It will return only part of the results. If `fullListArr` has 943 and `partialListArr` has 288 unique values, I should have 655 values in `arr` but I'm getting 895 and it is not returning it as a 2D array.

Here is a [sheet with a data set](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bOJcdFPKFSa-fjIYwHFQh9a_SgdEWm4Nll5sqsW7cO8/edit?usp=sharing) and both of these included.

**Attempts:** First I need to flatten if using the first function.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var partialListArr = ss.getSheetByName('sheet 2').getRange(1,1,357,1).getValues();
  var fullListArr = ss.getSheetByName('sheet 1').getRange(1,1,942,1).getValues();

  var flatPartialListArr = [].concat.apply([], partialListArr);
  var flatFullListArr = [].concat.apply([], fullListArr);

  var arr = flatFullListArr.filter(function(item){
    return flatPartialListArr.indexOf(item) === -1;
  }); 

  Logger.log(arr.length)
  Logger.log(arr)
```

That gave me the correct number for `arr`. Next step is to make it a 2d array again for me to plug it in `.setValues`. Here is the function with the full solution.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var partialListArr = ss.getSheetByName('sheet 2').getRange(1,1,357,1).getValues();
  var fullListArr = ss.getSheetByName('sheet 1').getRange(1,1,942,1).getValues();

  var flatPartialListArr = [].concat.apply([], partialListArr);
  var flatFullListArr = [].concat.apply([], fullListArr);

  var flatArr = flatFullListArr.filter(function(item){
    return flatPartialListArr.indexOf(item) === -1;
  }); 

  //Convert to 2D again for input into .setValues
  var newArr = [];
  while(flatArr.length) newArr.push(flatArr.splice(0,1));

  Logger.log(newArr.length)
  Logger.log(newArr)

  return newArr;
}
```

Thank you Akrion!

Comment: can you provide what is the structure of `item`? It seems your filtering is ok but maybe the `id` field is not the one you should be filtering on?

Comment: @Akrion I've linked a sheet so you can take a look at the data.

Comment: the sheet gives me the raw sheet data but not the actual objects that contain it. It seems `ss.getSheetByName('sheet 2').getRange(1,1,357,1).getValues()` for example does not return values but objects no? If no then why do you have `item.id`?

Comment: @Akrion The logs show [[60],[10004],[5678]....]

Comment: Exactly ... you have array of arrays :) which means you need to flatten this first before you itterate

Comment: @Akrion Does the second function do that? And if I flatten, I then have to convert to 2D?

Comment: @Akrion. Ok. I think I got it. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have something like this:

```js
var full = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
var partial = [[3],[4]]

var result = full.filter(x => !partial.find(p => p[0] === x[0]))
console.log(result)
```

This will filter the way you want. Simply put your filter does not work since you did not take into account the result returned, which is [[], [], []] or array of arrays.

So in your context try this:

```
var arr = fullListArr.filter(item => !partialListArr.find(p ==> p[0] === item[0]);
```

Comment: Arrow and `find` are not available in Apps Script

Comment: I have tried to use a similar solution to this but I get a syntax error. I'm assuming it's because google apps script does not take `=>`. I could be wrong.

Comment: @tehhowch You beat me to it. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @DanCue well it does not matter that much you ware able to solve it once you figured out that the array of arrays was the issue right?

Comment: @tehhowch thanks I did not test there but in the console so that was a good correction.

Comment: @Akrion That is correct. Do you want to post my solution so you can get the credit since it was thanks to you?

Comment: No that is fine. You can just accept the answer and add a note that you took that approach and got the solution. Either way is fine it is up to you. Glad you solved the issue. Rest is just numbers :)